# Software for Windows 7 that detects if someone photographs your screen

Tags: windows-7, camera

I'm looking for software that detects if someone is trying to photograph your screen with an external camera (hidden or not hidden).

[Hidden Camera Detector](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hidden-camera-detector/id532882360?mt=8) is an iOS app that can do something similar.

Comment: *with external camera*? You cannot detect anyone using a camera to photograph your computer screen.

Comment: Thanks Jan, there are applications for mobile phones that detect hidden cameras, why won't it work for PC?

Comment: @Avi: could you provide a link to such an app? I doubt that works, especially for the hidden ones

Comment: Here is one of them: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hidden-camera-detector/id532882360?mt=8

Comment: Basically any software that says it can do that is a con @Avi - anything that detected a camera as being something consisting of a lens with a light absorbing layer behind it would think that your eyes were cameras.

Comment: Read the reviews...

Comment: You all discuss how will it be implemented. I think that any technology that detects cameras (visually) or new lens with a light absorbing layer behind (omitting the current eyes of user) can help me. The one who wants to snap shot is a new object/ len in the space.

Comment: This requires a camera on the PC screen which can see any point from which you can see the screen.  That means you need the user's cooperation.  As one example, on my PC, you can't do that at all, because my camera is physically covered unless I ever wish to use the camera.  And if your site/app required a camera and I wished to use your site/app and take a picture of the screen, I'd spoof the image you receive.  Heck, I might spoof it even if I didn't want to take a picture.  Oh, and my work computers don't even have cameras.